# if any(word in 'x' for word in list): is not working well

Tags: python, words

I was using the `if any(word in 'x' for word in list):` into a cycle in order to know if any of some words (in a list) were in specific texts in order to discard the ones for which none of the words was present. It used to work pretty fine but, from a couple of months ago the conditional expression starts to give always positive results.

For example:

```
list=['home','cat']
if any(word in "my home is red" for word in list):
    print "YES" 
YES
if any(word in "my hair is red" for word in list):
    print "YES" 
YES
```

But the second conditional is supposed to show me a negative result. I didn't change anything in my previous code but anyway I can be making some stupid mistake which someone could help me?

Comment: This code is running as I would expect it would. The first `any` returns `True `and the second returns `False`

Comment: Are you using NumPy or a setup configured to auto-run `from numpy import *`?

Comment: as a general rule, it is bad practice to override a reserved word as you have done with `list`. try to use a more descriptive name.

Comment: Side-note: Don't name variables `list`; it's a great way to get really confused when you try to convert some other iterable to a `list` and oops, `list` isn't the `list` constructor anymore.

Comment: @HaleemurAli: `list` isn't technically "reserved", it's just a built-in name. [Very few names in Python are actually restricted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html), it's just a bad idea to shadow the built-ins.

Comment: @idjaw: Except they're claiming both return `True`... That said, I don't see any way for this to be the case unless they're mistaken as to the contents of `list`. This smells like user error that the minimal example doesn't display.

Comment: It doesn't look like the questioner stuck around. I'm dupe-hammering based on the probable NumPy explanation. If it turns out it's not using `numpy.any`, we can always reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the second "YES" comes from the second line?  Change your code to

```
mylist=['home','cat']
if any(word in "my home is red" for word in mylist):
    print "YES" 
else:
    print "NO"

if any(word in "my hair is red" for word in mylist):
    print "YES" 
else:
    print "NO"
```

When I run this, I get

```
YES
NO
```